# Package via Items dynamically not working

Tags: packages, package-designer

I want to create a package for items that were created or updated in the last 30 days. I am using the **[Items Dynamically](https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/creating-dynamic-packages-with-sitecore-package-designer)** feature to create the package.

Initially, I created two new items with names starting with **NewItem**. Then, I selected **Items Dynamically** and left the Item Name filter empty. However, when I created the package, it didn't contain any items

[image]

Realizing the issue, I selected **Items Dynamically** again and this time I included **NewItem** in the Item Name filter. When I generated the package, the new items were correctly added.

It should have worked in the first attempt when the Item name filter was empty. I want to add all the items that were created or updated in the last 30 days.

Is there any other way of creating a package to add all the items that were created or updated in the last 30 days? I can do via PowerShell but I need to know is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use asterisk character as a name filter, and use `Wildcards` option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding items dynamically to a package doesn’t store a list of items. It stores a starting point (search root item) and optional filters to narrow down the selection of items in the sub-tree that descends from the root item. The final list of items to be exported is determined at the moment you do the export (when you click **Generate ZIP**).

I tried your steps with my local instance and it works fine without specifying the `item name filter`.

Reref the below steps:

1. Created 2 items called `NewItem` and `NewItem 2`.

[image]

2. Goto `Package designer` -> click on `Item Dynamically` -> Select the root item as `Home`.

[image]

3. Added `30` days in `Creation date filter`.

[image]

4. Added source name and click add button.
5. If you wish you can take a look to preview package items by clicking `Preview` button.

[image]

6. Finally click on `Generate ZIP` button.

Furthermore, try troubleshooting with the below steps.

1. Check if there is any error logged in the log file.
2. Try to create a separate package one with `created` filter, and one with a `modified` filter. If you create on with both filters in that case some of your items that have both `Created Date` and `Updated Date` in that period will be included twice in the same content package and on import that would create two identical versions on your item. Because of that it’s best to keep these two content packages separate.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using the item dynamically feature worked for me to create the package of items that were created or updated in the last 30 days. I tested in Sitecore 10.2.

The dynamic export of items that have been created or modified in the past X days relies on the Created Date and Updated Date on each of the items. Based on these values Sitecore will determine if a particular item needs to be included in the package or not.

I read about this issue (for old Sitecore versions) with Created Date and Updated Date not always being updated by Sitecore. The problematic functionalities are:

- Copy Item
- Duplicate Item

Check this article for more details.

https://www.coria.com/en/insights/blog/Sitecore/sitecore-content-sync-and-the-update-date-problem

Not sure what version of Sitecore you are using to test this. But if you are not getting anything in the logs then you can find out the logic written behind this and try to debug it by creating your custom class.

Hope this helps.